# MySQL alter table add column with primary key syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a column to one of of my database tables, but there is a syntax error
and I can't seem to find the problem...

My current database table looks like this:

```
component   +  tag_id  +  item_id
------------|----------|-----------
com_content |    23    |    2642
com_content |    26    |    3481
com_content |    35    |    1868
com_content |    85    |    5827
com_content |    89    |    7882
```

I want it to look like this, where 'id' is auto increment and all columns part of the primary key

```
 id  +  component   +  tag_id  +  item_id
-----|--------------|----------|-----------
  1  |  com_content |    23    |    2642
  2  |  com_content |    26    |    3481
  3  |  com_content |    35    |    1868
  4  |  com_content |    85    |    5827
  5  |  com_content |    89    |    7882
```

This is my query:

```
DROP PRIMARY KEY
ALTER TABLE gitags_items
ADD COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST
PRIMARY KEY (id,component,tag_id,item_id)
```

However I'm getting this error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY ALTER TABLE gitags_items ADD COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INC' at line 1
```

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The 'ALTER TABLE' bit must come first, and then each part must be seperated by a comma:

```
ALTER TABLE gitags_items
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id,component,tag_id,item_id);
```

but I'm not sure if you can drop and create a primary key in the same staatement.

Answer (score 2):

This one works fine, there was the problem with the commas, theres no need to drop the primary key since your going to set one yourself

```
ALTER TABLE gitags_items ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,component,tag_id,item_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make 'id' column primary key before setting autoincrement.

Comment: This was a problem back around v3 - in current versions, there's only a constraint for MyISAM tables where the autoincrement value must be the first entry in the index. "For MyISAM tables, you can specify an AUTO_INCREMENT secondary column in a multiple-column key" - from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code to **my.cnf**

```
sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO"
```

then, restart MySQL

```
# service mysqld restart
```