# Replace if exists or insert in mySQL database from Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, replace, insert

I would like to replace a value if the date/time for a row in table is the same for the one he try to insert. If the time/date doesn't exist in the table then insert it.

If you se the picture. The value nr 2 to the end has the same time as the first value. Then it should replace the first one because they have the same time. Not get added last to the list. If the time doesn't exist, then it can be added.

I have tried with REPLACE and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but I cant get it to work...

```
"INSERT INTO flowAvarageValuesDays (time, value) VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE avarageFlowValueDays=%s", (time,value,value)
```

and

```
"REPLACE INTO flowAvarageValuesDays (time, value) VALUES (%s, %s)",
            (time, value)
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXDLZ.png)

Comment: I cant get it to work... is not very helpful. Post code [mcve] and the full traceback you get

Comment: Is the time column a key? It won't work unless it's a key.

Comment: How can I set the tiem column as a key ?

Comment: @PederWard: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19950545/42346

Comment: You can add condition for your query if(time = (SELECT time FROM table WHERE %s IN (time),INSERT,UPDATE)
If time doesn't exist then it will insert else update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF(SELECT time FROM table WHERE %s IN(time), INSERT INTO flowAvarageValuesDays (time, value) VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE avarageFlowValueDays=%s, (time,value),REPLACE INTO flowAvarageValuesDays (time, value) VALUES (%s, %s),
```

(time, value))